# Make side by side divs have same height as one another

Tags: html, css

I have three side by side divs inside a `<td>` (not ideal I know).
These are styled so that the font-size, line-height and width adjust based on viewport width.The text may flow over 2-4 lines which is fine.I need each `<div>` to be the same height as the tallest of the three side by side `<div>`'s.

I have wrapped the `<div>`'s in a wrapper with `class='infowrap'` as I presume I can style this wrapper to have the effect I am looking for? - but I am not sure how.

```css
.infobox {
  background-color: #f0f0df;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5vw;
  padding: 0.5vw;
  width: 12vw;
  line-height: 2vw;
  border-radius: 0.25vw;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-shadow: 0px 0.1vw 0px 0px grey;
  font-size: 2vw;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  margin-right: 5vw;

}
```

```html
<div class=infowrap>
  <div class=infobox><span class="mobhide">blurb</span>
    <p><b>more stuff here</b>
  </div>
  <div class=infobox><span class="mobhide">blurb</span>
    <p><b>more stuff here</b>
  </div>
  <div class=infobox><span class="mobhide">blurb</span>
    <p><b>more stuff here</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Flexbox**

```css
.infowrap {
  display: flex;
}

.infobox {
  flex: 1;
  background: #F0F0DF;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class=infowrap>
  <div class=infobox>
    <span class="mobhide">blurb</span>
    <p><b>more stuff here</b>
  </div>
  <div class=infobox>
    <span class="mobhide">blurb</span>
    <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam omnis maxime ullam veniam.</b>
  </div>
  <div class=infobox>
    <span class="mobhide">blurb</span>
    <p><b>more stuff here</b>
  </div>
</div>
```

[MDN Flexbox Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_flexible_boxes)

Comment: how can you 'vertical-align:center;' with that. I tried changing that as I had it as 'vertical-align:top' in my original fiddle, but it doesn't center align the text across the 'flexbox' height?

Comment: that just seems to not make the div's not resize anymore, but just moves them to be vertically aligned?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox which is preferred, but is not supported in IE<11.

As an alternative, instead of using 3 divs, you can create another table with 3 columns. Tables automatically cause all of the columns to be the same height.

I recommend tables or a CSS-only solution instead of using JS for this for the sake of stability and page speed.

As a rule of thumb, you should avoid using JS for DOM manipulation whenever possible.

Comment: I don't want to go down the route of table inside a table to be honest. I am already not happy I am using a table instead of div's but I can't work out how to code my way back out of table's with the <script> I have!